# Is it possible to perform calculations on a TimeStamp index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

let's say I have something like

```
dates = pd.Series([
  pd.Timestamp('20140102'),
  pd.Timestamp('20140104'),
  pd.Timestamp('20140106'),
  pd.Timestamp('20140110'),
  pd.Timestamp('20140112'),
  pd.Timestamp('20140113')
])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]), index=dates, columns=['a'])
```

My goal is to be able to do a map on the a column, but with a knowledge of the related index.

A dumb example function would be

```
df1['a'].specialmap(lambda x: time)
```

such that now the a column just has the corresponding time index in it

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, what is it you want to do here?

Comment: updated the question to hopefully be clearer

Comment: You have to pass a series or dict where the index/key values are your `df1` values, otherwise you need to write a function that takes the passed index value, essentially yes you can do it

Comment: Thanks! would it be possible for you to answer with a short example? I'm pretty new to pandas and am still getting used to a model

Comment: Which do you want? mapping ints 1..6 to some value or mapping your timestamp index to some value?

Comment: How about this, I want there to be a new column 'b' whose value is equal to the value in 'a' * the timestamp value as an epoch time

Comment: Sorry are you looking for this `def func(x):
    return x.name.timestamp() * x
df1.apply(func, axis=1)`?

Comment: aha! row.name! brilliant, that's what I didn't know existed :) <3<3<3<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to perform some kind of timestamp calculation using your index you can call `apply` and access the index using the `name` attribute:

```
In [60]:
def func(x):
    return x.name.timestamp() * x
df1.apply(func, axis=1)
​
Out[60]:
                     a
2014-01-02  1388620800
2014-01-04  2777587200
2014-01-06  4166899200
2014-01-10  5557248000
2014-01-12  6947424000
2014-01-13  8337427200
```